Python global counter for multiprocessing pool
I want to keep count how many items have already been processed, but I get an error. Here's my minimal code and the error stack trace.
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Value
from ctypes import c_int

class DemoProcessor(object):


    def __init__(self, data_to_process):
        self.counter = Value(c_int, 0)
        self.data_to_process = data_to_process
        
    def _process_data(self, item):
        print (f"Processing {item}")
        self.counter.value = self.counter.value + 1
        print (f"Processed {self.counter.value}")
        
    def process(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        results_multi = pool.starmap(self._process_data, self.data_to_process),
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo = DemoProcessor(data_to_process=list(range(10)))
    demo.process()
        

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 23, in <module>
    demo.process()
  File "demo.py", line 19, in process
    results_multi = pool.starmap(self._process_data, self.data_to_process),
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 199, in __reduce__
    assert_spawning(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 359, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    


I think you want to put the multiprocessing.Value as class variable to the class DemoProcessor, e.g.:
import multiprocessing
from ctypes import c_int
from multiprocessing import Value
from random import random
from time import sleep


class DemoProcessor(object):
    counter = Value(c_int, 0)

    def __init__(self, data_to_process):
        self.data_to_process = data_to_process

    def _process_data(self, item):
        print(f"Processing {item=}")
        sleep(random() * 5)
        DemoProcessor.counter.value = DemoProcessor.counter.value + 1
        print(f"Processed {item=} {DemoProcessor.counter.value=}")

    def process(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        _ = pool.starmap(self._process_data, self.data_to_process)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = DemoProcessor(data_to_process=[(i,) for i in range(10)])
    demo.process()

Prints (for example):
Processing item=0
Processing item=1
Processing item=2
Processing item=3
Processed item=0 DemoProcessor.counter.value=1
Processing item=4
Processed item=2 DemoProcessor.counter.value=2
Processing item=5
Processed item=1 DemoProcessor.counter.value=3
Processing item=6
Processed item=5 DemoProcessor.counter.value=4
Processing item=7
Processed item=3 DemoProcessor.counter.value=5
Processing item=8
Processed item=4 DemoProcessor.counter.value=6
Processing item=9
Processed item=8 DemoProcessor.counter.value=7
Processed item=7 DemoProcessor.counter.value=8
Processed item=6 DemoProcessor.counter.value=9
Processed item=9 DemoProcessor.counter.value=10


Thanks, but I get race conditions when number of item becomes > 100, and I don't use sleep. How do I go around this?

@BaronYugovich I'm not sure what is the goal, but probably you can try multiprocessing.Lock

Sorry about the confusion, let me clarify: the goal is to print correct number of done processes at each point in time. Now, if I run for 100 items with 4 processed, the largest printed number I get at the end is 86, due to race conditions.
